# Sharepoint 2007 get link to items in a custom form

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I have a SharePoint Server 2007 installation. What I needed to do is to create a simple printable page/file which is populated with data from a list. For various bugs and reasons I can't do this with a word template in a word document library and I can't use workflows.

My solution so far is very rude and simple, but it gets the jobs done:

1. I created a new custom form called print.aspx
2. I insert a Custom List Form based on the display form.
3. Successfully pasted the text, put the data fields and added a couple of text fields for additional data that is required in the print form but not on the list item.

This `print.aspx` custom form won't save anything and it is not required.

Now what I want to do is place a link in the customized `DispForm.aspx` that leads to the printing page so when the user enters the list item and it is approved they can click to see it. At the bottom of the `DispForm.aspx` there will be a simple link to `print.aspx` saying "*To print this click here*". Unfortunately I have no idea how to link to the ID of the item in print.aspx.

Example:
In `InternalPortal/Lists/ImportantList/DispForm.aspx?ID=5` I want the link to point to `InternalPortal/Lists/ImportantList/print.aspx?ID=5`

Already tried `ID={@ID}` and `ID=item.ID` but to be honest and not sure how to use them.

**Edit:** In summary - the link ends in `ID={@ID}` but it should be in the DataFormWebPart. This will not work outside of it.

Comment: The simple `print.aspx` page is generally the right approach. What master page is it based on? SharePoint 2007 processes the ID parameter automatically in certain cases and provides you with a `SPContext.Current.ListItem`.

Comment: @OndrejTucny thanks but how does this help me? What should I use at the end in the link I've manually put on DispForm.aspx to point to the same list item's print.aspx? As far as I know the master page has not been modified and this is the default team sites template. And thanks again for your time.

Comment: Ok, so I found the answer. It is indeed `ID={@ID}` so the whole link is `InternalPortal/Lists/ImportantList/print.aspx?ID={@ID}`.
HOWEVER it works only if the link is in the DataFormWebPart. In my case I just added a Custom List Form below the default one, deleted everything in it and put the link. Now everything works.